# How to make classes in NACHOS (C++)

Tags: c++, class, nachos

I am trying to implement a player class, so I created two files in my threads folder,
player.cc and player.h

player.h goes like this :

```
#ifndef PLAYER_H
#define PLAYER_H
#include "utility.h"

class Player()
{
  public:
   //getPlayerID();
};

#endif
```

then player.cc goes like

```
#include "player.h"

class Player()
{
  string playerID;
  int timeCycle;
}
```

Then in my main.cc and threadtest.cc , I add in #include player.h and then I start to errors and it fails to compile. I am new to nachos and a little bit unfamiliar with c++, so I am confused as to how to resolve this problem. Nachos does not provide a solution through the compiler either.

When I type gmake, it says two things for errors.
1. parse error before '(' in player.h (referring to Player())
2. *** [main.o] Error 1

Comment: IIRC, NachOS is an academic operating system (which means this is probably homework). What are you trying to do?

Comment: well it supports c or c++ to some extent as a lot of these files are .cc  //On a second note, it might not implement a full C++ runtime, but it is capable of running c++ files and I just need to figure how to get mine to work ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's go through line-by-line:

```
#ifndef PLAYER_H
#define PLAYER_H
#include "utility.h"
```

So far so good, you might check if your compiler supports `#pragma once`, but the macro will work perfectly fine.

```
class Player()
```

`()` aren't allowed in a class name, take them off

```
{
  public:
   //getPlayerID();
};

#endif
```

The rest of the header file is ok.  Let's look at the implementation file:

```
#include "player.h"
```

Perfect.  Putting a class in a header is the best way to make sure you only have one definition used in your whole program.

```
class Player()
```

Parentheses aren't allowed, but here you have a bigger problem.  You already have a class with that name.  Let the header provide the class definition, the implementation file just needs to provide the non-inline member functions (and any helper code).

```
{
  string playerID;
  int timeCycle;
}
```

Here's a complete corrected version:

```
#if !defined(PLAYER_H)
#define PLAYER_H

#include <string>
#include "utility.h"

class Player
{
     std::string player_id;
     int time_cycle;

public:
     // this is how you make a constructor, the parenthesis belong here, not on the class name
     Player(std::string id, int time);

     std::string getPlayerId() const;
};

#endif /* !defined(PLAYER_H) */
```

and implementation file

```
#include "player.h"

// and this is how you write a non-inline constructor
Player::Player(std::string id, int time)
    : player_id(id)
    , time_cycle(time)
{}

std::string Player::getPlayerId() const
{
    return player_id;
}
```

All of these problems are really basic C++ stuff, nothing to do with NachOS.

Comment: This works great and it compiles now. But now let's say I wanted to initialize a player with both a playerID and timeCycle. 

I originally put player() because I wanted to change it to player(string playerID, int timeCycle) .

From what I know, getters and setters are done differently in c++

Comment: @krikara: The constructor declaration goes INSIDE the class.  I'll edit with an example.

Comment: #include <string.h> should be #include <string> . Otherwise you include the C file.

Comment: and in the constructor u miss the namespace :-)

Answer (score 1):

Did you modify the Makefile.common in the root nachos directory? I think you should add some value to `THREAD_H`, `THREAD_O` and `THREAD_C`.